# Can I insert my data-context in the text suggestions bar?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Suggestions bar: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC530993.png
I'd like to know if there's a way to put my data in this bar programmatically.

Comment: You mean like this: http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2012/12/06/the-secrets-of-the-windows-phone-8-keyboard.aspx?

Comment: I created my own bar, but "Paste" button spoils the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't add words to the Predictive Text bar in the Windows Phone.

What you can do is use the autocomplete feature:

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_Auto_Complete_Box_in_Windows_Phone

And don't forget to add the scope of the keyboard

```
   <TextBox>
    <TextBox.InputScope>
     <InputScope>
       <InputScopeName NameValue="Text" />
     </InputScope>
    </TextBox.InputScope>
  </TextBox>
```

There are multiple Input Scopes

```
<TextBox Name="myTextBox" InputScope="Text"/>
```

There are ways to enumerate this as this [post points out](http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2010/07/06/WP7-InputScope.aspx)

```
var inputScopes = new List<string>();

FieldInfo[] array = typeof(InputScopeNameValue).GetFields(
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
foreach (FieldInfo fi in array)
{
    inputScopes.Add(fi.Name);
}

this.DataContext = inputScopes;
```

1. AddressCity
2. AddressCountryName
3. AddressCountryShortName
4. AddressStateOrProvince
5. AddressStreet
6. AlphanumericFullWidth
7. AlphanumericHalfWidth
8. ApplicationEnd
9. Bopomofo
10. Chat
11. CurrencyAmount
12. CurrencyAmountAndSymbol
13. CurrencyChinese
14. Date
15. DateDay
16. DateDayName
17. DateMonth
18. DateMonthName
19. DateYear
20. Default
21. Digits
22. EmailNameOrAddress
23. EmailSmtpAddress
24. EmailUserName
25. EnumString
26. FileName
27. FullFilePath
28. Hanja
29. Hiragana
30. KatakanaFullWidth
31. KatakanaHalfWidth
32. LogOnName
33. Maps
34. NameOrPhoneNumber
35. Number
36. NumberFullWidth
37. OneChar
38. Password
39. PersonalFullName
40. PersonalGivenName
41. PersonalMiddleName
42. PersonalNamePrefix
43. PersonalNameSuffix
44. PersonalSurname
45. PhraseList
46. PostalAddress
47. PostalCode
48. Private
49. RegularExpression
50. Search
51. Srgs
52. TelephoneAreaCode
53. TelephoneCountryCode
54. TelephoneLocalNumber
55. TelephoneNumber
56. Text
57. Time
58. TimeHour
59. TimeMinorSec
60. Url
61. Xml
62. Yomi